# Installing Imagemagick php extension on hosted server

Tags: php, installation, imagemagick, pecl, hosted

hoping someone will be able to help me.

I'm trying to install ImageMagick on a (Linux) server hosted at 1&1. I've managed to install ImageMagick itself, but I can't for the life of me manage to install the PHP PECL extension, and can't figure out if it's even possible without 1&1 doing it for me.

What do I need to have access to to be able to install the PECL plugin? Do I need access to the PHP installation itself? Do I need them to activate the extension for me? I was on the phone with them now, and they didn't seem very willing, but at the same time I'm pretty sure the guy I spoke with didn't really have a clue what this was about anyways.

Would be extremely thankful for tips!

Comment: You may have better luck posting on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/pecl). Assuming you have root access to the server, you can install through the distros package-manager (yum, apt-get, &tc), through pecl utility, or compile from [source](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I guess I don't have root access, as this is a hosted virtual server. So I guess the actual PHP installation are shared, and I won't be able to access it?